# ManipulationMode not found in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am new to Windows Phone app development. I am trying to do some image manipulation (basically rotation) in Windows Phone 8.1. I am able to configure Manipulation event properties like ManipulationDelta, ManipulationStarted & ManipulationCompleted without any error except ManipulationMode.

I am getting the issue as below:

```
The member "ManipulationMode" is not recognized or is not accessible. 
The property 'ManipulationMode' was not found in type 'Image'
```

I think I am missing some namespaces required for that. I am struggling for long time.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure it's a `windows phone 8.1` and not a `windows phone 8.1 silverlight` project?

Comment: Yes, Windows phone Silverlight project - Pivot application template.

Comment: it's not available for that platform

Comment: oh my bad. I thought both are similar. Thanks a lot thumbmunkeys!